# Dynamic DNS replacement for my home router: Do I understand the pricing of Amazon route 53 correctly?

Tags: amazon-route53, dynamic-dns

I'm seeing here the [prices for Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/pricing/). I'm a rookie on this, so I'm not sure if I understand their price scheme. According to them, a hosted zone will cost me $0.50 per month plus 0.50 per million queries.

Here is my question:

If a query is roughly equivalent to say, a web visit, and I have less than 1 million visits per month, then I should end-up paying around $1 per month for the DNS services? Is this correct? Or is there any cost that I'm not accounting for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely pay $0.50 or $0.51 a month. DNS queries are cached, so a user should really only be making a billable DNS query every once in a while. For dynamic DNS a TTL of 10 minutes is probably a good idea, for other stuff an hour or a day is common.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with your pricing being off. Reading helps:

> The query prices listed above are prorated;

That is not 0.50 USD - it is 0.50 USD per 1 million queries and a low volume home system will not ahve more than a couple of thousand. SHould round to 0 or 1 cent.

Second, not every visit is a DNS hit - DNS uses extensive distributed caching, so it all depends. Things get complicated here - as caching is configurable (a) by you (per zone) and (b) depends where the hits come from (provider) as basically the DNS server the client uses is the caching point, not a hierarchy. Realistically I would expect maximum a coupel of thousand hits (max 10.000) for a typical home website.

That said - quite obviously - this is not something to discuss here as you lack - per the rules of this site - the authority to ask a question. Voting to close (not relevant question in professional admin capacity.

THAT AGAIN being said - use entrydns, that is free and more than enough for your needs. No sense in signing up for a service for 50 cents per month, especially when there is a free alterantive. I use entrydns for some time now and am very happy (entrydns.net).

Comment: Thanks for helping. I've been bouncing from free DNS service to free DNS service, and my last one decided quite suddenly to go from free to charge $7 per month in its most basic plan.

Comment: "a hosted zone with 100,000 standard queries would be charged $0.050" that confused me too. Is that total or is that for queries? Seems your interpretation is correct, but the confusion doesn't surprise me.

Comment: I would like to apologize for my miss-understanding, I thought that this was a public Q&A website. I'm also sorry for being so lame and having the small webserver of my company at home... I don't earn a living exactly for being a Linux system administrator, that's something that I just have been doing out of necessity for the last ten years.

Comment: This site is for professional admins as per FAQ. "Server Fault is a site for system and network administrators needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.". Home setups are generally not welcome here. Also: "and it is not about… Anything in a home or development environment" - as per help pages.

Comment: And here Comes the anonymous Coward downvote. Nice.

Comment: @TomTom Ah, didn't see your comment before. I am neither anonymous, nor a coward. I found your answer to be unreasonably snarky.